# How do I change the text size of result displayed via Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: font, siri, shortcuts-app

If I ask Siri for e.g. the price of bitcoin, it shows a nicely formatted text like down below

[image]

With Shortcuts, I can display a dialog with arbitrary content, with the "Display Result" action.  However, I have no control over the text formatting.

On an Apple Watch, this is especially bad, as the font size is very small, even when the text is short. I can increase the default font size of the Watch, but then all of the text will be bigger anywhere else, even when the content to display is longer, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to manipulate the text formatting -- or at least the font size -- of Siri Shortcuts output?

Answer (score 0):

I have one small idea - change font size in system (shortcuts/apps/settings/accessibility) then make popup and resize font to normal state.